# Pip not able to find wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a virtual environment. Since a couple of days I cannot run any pip commands and am getting the error:

```
  File "env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
ImportError: No module named wheel
```

I have wheel in the site-packages and it was installed earlier. how do I resolve this? I cannot use any pip commands.

Comment: What version of `pip` is this? `pip -V`.

Comment: Similar problems are usually caused when using different methods to manage python packages, i.e. pip and apt-get/yum. (And/or when messed with virtual environment and system Python packages.) I would suggest to get wheel module and install it with `easy_install` explicitly specifying the Python interpreter to use.

Comment: @Nikita: this isn't an issue with the `wheel` package. The `pip` installation appears to be corrupted; e.g. `pip.index` tries to import `pip.wheel`, but the latter is missing.

Comment: @Martijn You got it right. Even pip -v won't run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pip` installation appears to be broken. It is not the `wheel` project that is the problem here, it is the `pip.wheel` package (part of `pip` itself) that fails to import; it looks like `/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py` is either missing or has been corrupted somehow.

I'd reinstall `pip` at this point.

Comment: pip seems to be working in a different virtual environment, just not with this one environment.

Comment: @user3548288: it is corrupted in this specific environment. `/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/` would normally contain a `wheel.py` file, but in your case that appears to be missing or otherwise broken.

Comment: I just pasted wheel.py from other vitual env's pip folder to this virtual env's pip folder and it started working :D Thanks Martijn